# password on resume

Tags: password, lock-screen

I would like to not have to enter my password on resume after closing the lid on my laptop.  I used to be able to do this but can't find the option anywhere anymore.  all the notes I have found say go to "Screensaver" but when I type "Screensaver" into the dash, nothing comes up.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the lock screen's password request via the **Settings -> Brightness and Lock -> Lock** section.

There you can toggle the password request, and whether or not the screen should be automatically locked. (You can still lock the screen via the normal **Lock Screen** UI button, or respective command.)