# Ubuntu 13.10 and 12.04 ask for password when unlocking

Tags: password, session

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and 12.04 installed on 2 pc,in both ones I don't want Ubuntu to ask for password when unlocking session,I disabled it from options but it's still asking for it,it doesn't when booting,but it does when unlocking,how can I do it? In the locking settings it says "Ask for passowrd every time coming back from suspension",I disabled it but it's still asking.Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [password on resume](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217706/password-on-resume)

Comment: I did what's been said there,but it still asks for password.

Comment: Yes I am,it looks like a gap that says (I'm traslating from Spanish) "Ask for passowrd every time coming back from suspension",I disabled it but it's still asking.

Comment: Ah,I wasn't understanding,so if I disable locking,will it power off the monitor? Does it have any risk to not lock? (It's my home computer so anybody will enter phisically, but I don't know by internet or any other way...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lock/Unlock screen was designed to prevent someone else in the room, your friend, or family member, to get into your computer when you go and get a cup of coffee. This does not do anything about someone hacking into your computer using the Internet.

See the picture below:

[image]

If you want to turn the screen off when you are not around, change <kbd>**Never**</kbd> to something else. This will save energy, but will not add any security.

If you don't want your spouse to read your emails, you lock screen. To unlock screen you will need password. (Don't tell the password to your spouse.) If you don't have a spouse then set **Lock** to OFF as shown in the image above.

Hope this helps