# How do I make my Ubuntu 18.04 hibernate and automatically wake up at specified time and play radio in rhythmbox?

Tags: 18.04, suspend

I am a new user. I want to sleep now and let my computer wake me up at given time playing radio in rhythmbox. Is there a way.. even if system wakes up from hibernation, it would ask for password..?

Comment: There are really three different questions here. **1:** How to wake computer at certain time: https://askubuntu.com/questions/113379/suspend-and-wake-pc-at-certain-time **2.** How to play music with Rhythm Box at certain time: https://askubuntu.com/questions/473269/starting-rhythmbox-via-crontab **3.** Password when waking/resuming: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217706/password-on-resume